# How can I send a PDF file with its file name in Twilio WhatsApp?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I am having trouble sending a PDF file through WhatsApp with its file name. It is sent without the name regardless of where it is hosted, of the properties of the PDF, and everything I imagined.

I tried changing the hosting locations of the file (AWS/WordPress/Media libraries), I completed all metadata in PDF properties, and I still receive the files without its title. I also changed the files, and for every PDF I tried the problem was the same.

This is the code:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC_XXXXXXX/Messages.json \
  --data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+11111111" \
  --data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:+1111111" \
  --data-urlencode "Body=Menú de Kenko" \
  --data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://gentl.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/kenko-menu.pdf" \
  -u 'AC_XXXXXXXX:AUTH_TOKEN'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by title? are you referring to the title property of a pdf?

Comment: See this screenshot: https://ibb.co/k8G9Gsn 
The file is being sent as if it had no name

Comment: @MateoCriado currently this is not supported by the twilio whatsApp send Message API, we can only send images with text.